# Django button to send emails

Tags: ajax, django

How would you go about creating a button in your templates of an app in Django. I have a script in my views.py:

```
def my_python_script(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        # stuff here
    else:
        return HttpRequest(status=400)
```

But how do I actually turn this into a button? Is there some html or css I need to put somewhere? I saw some things about a templates directory in the application but I'm unsure on what things to put there and in what formats.

Comment: You need to start at the beginning of the django tutorial and work through it.

Answer (score 1):

You would do like the following:

```
<button type='button' id="my_button">Click me</button>
```

And with a js (jquery):

```
$("#my_button").click(){
     $.get("url_to_view",{data:"data",function(response){
          // response to do something after the request
     });
});
```